# Laravel Eloquent setAppends() to entire model collection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

As per https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization, one can use `setAppends` on a model instance to dynamically add any available extra attributes to a model. However, I haven't been able to find a way to do this to a collection of models, aside from looping through the collection.

Is there a smarter way to do this? Like so:

```
$facilities = Facility:all();
$facilities->setAppends();
```

Currently the only option would be:

```
foreach ($facilities as $facility) {
    $facility->setAppends([
        'your_attribute_here'
    ]);
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, I want to do this dynamically at runtime. The extra properties I'm defining aren't needed everywhere where the model is fetched and can cause extra overhead in large quantities.

Comment: You don't need to do any additional work if you add the accessor and appends property.

Comment: @chanafdo Please see my edit at the bottom. I want to do this dynamically.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your model add the following accessor

```
public function getCustomAttribute()
{
    return 'some-value';
}
```

Define a `setAppends` macro on `Collection`, preferably in a Service Provider (e.g. AppServiceProvider) so you can use it anywhere:

```
Collection::macro('setAppends', function ($attributes) {
    return $this->map(function ($item) use ($attributes) {
        return $item->setAppends($attributes);
    });
});
```

Then you can do

```
$facilities = Facility:all();
$facilities->setAppends([
    'some-value'
]);
```

Comment: This works pretty well, thanks. Based off of this I've come up with a more generic version that can be used in the same way as the original function. However I'd like to understand something just to be sure. Does this macro not just do the same thing as looping through the entire collection like my example?

Also, should I use the edit feature on your answer to post a generic version or..? I'm not too sure on that part of SO etiquette.

Comment: Yes, Underneath it's just looping through and dynamically appending

Comment: Fair enough. I also found out more about Collection macros and saw that it would be good to put them in a service provider.

Comment: Yes. you can put it in `AppServiceProvider`

Comment: The thing is that there are multiple queries executed; one for each row in the collection. Is there a way to populate this with in a single query?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#higher-order-messages):

```
$facilities->each->setAppends([
    'your_attribute_here'
]);
```

Comment: Not sure it work like this. `each` receives a Closure, but even `$model->each(function ($row) { $row->setAppends([...]); })` does not work

Comment: My mistake, I was trying to apply `each` on a Query not on a Collection. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your model define `$appends` property and add your custom attributes like

```
protected $appends = ['your_attribute_here'];
```

To set value for these custom attributes define [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) method

```
public function getYourAttributeHereAttribute()
{
    return "some value or model attribute";
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit at the bottom. I want to do this dynamically.